# OpenCV / Array should be CvMat or IplImage / Releasing a capture object

Tags: python, opencv, camera, release, capture

**Edit :** `Array should be CvMat or IplImage` is not an error message specific to this issue, that's the only most relevant error message i got.

---

I'm trying to make an *.exe out of an application using opencv.

I'm using **Python 2.6** and **openCV 2.1**.

I can run part of the *.exe, i'm having a menu from where i can choose to process some pictures from 2 differents sources my webcam & a static image. The static image part works but when i'm chosing the webcam here is the output:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Array should be CvMat or IplImage) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxarray.cpp,
 line 1233
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 295, in 'calling callback function'
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.window.win32", line 849, in _wnd_proc
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.window.win32", line 918, in _event_key
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.window", line 1219, in dispatch_event
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.event", line 340, in dispatch_event
  File "", line 502, in on_key_press
  File "", line 461, in dostart
  File "", line 482, in getpoints
  File "D:\Prog\Python\AugmentedR\src\pyar.py", line 40, in get_points
    pilimage = Image.fromstring("RGB", cv.GetSize(image), image.tostring())
cv.error: Array should be CvMat or IplImage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 616, in 
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.app", line 264, in run
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.app.win32", line 63, in run
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.app.win32", line 84, in _timer_func
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.app", line 193, in idle
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.window", line 1219, in dispatch_event
  File "game_ar\build\pyi.win32\game_ar\outPYZ1.pyz/pyglet.event", line 340, in dispatch_event
  File "", line 546, in on_draw
AttributeError: Game instance has no attribute 'bg'
```

My [pyar.py](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/345671/) file.

Building the *.exe with py2exe gave me this output :

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['ICCProfile', '_imaging_gif', '_scproxy']
```

I don't get it, this is working with my sources. I tried to pack my application with py2exe & pyinstaller, but the output is the same.

I guess the *.exe is missing something but i don't know what neither how to debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not related to the packagers.

The problem was that I wasn't closing the webcam capture, several processes of my app were actually running in the background.

The [doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=releasecapture) is talking about `ReleaseCapture` but this function is apparently not in the python bindings, calling :

`del(self.cam)`

did the job just well, `self.cam` being my `CvCapture` object.