# cant find ReleaseCapture in opencv while using python?

Tags: python, opencv, capture

I am trying to release a cam capture which has been acquired by the API call

```
    camera = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
```

How can I release it. There is a function named "ReleaseCapture" but it has no python binding.

Can anybody suggest any alternative?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you file a feature request for OpenCV with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a similar answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140230/opencv-array-should-be-cvmat-or-iplimage-releasing-a-capture-object)

```
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

#some code ...

del(capture)
```

be carefull of using *frame* or another image captured from cam after deleting *capture*

regards