# how can we start and stop the webcam in opencv?

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I am trying to capture images from webcam using opencv. When i call cvQueryFrame() the image is read and the cam starts. I want cam to stop because it will be used by other application.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't cvReleaseCapture() working ?

I would just stop the frame query, (stop the loop you use to capture frame) and then simply release the capture...
Is it what you are searching for ?
[Here is the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=releasecapture#cvReleaseCapture)

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I can see that this is an obvious solution. The problem is I am using opencv from python. There is no binding for the method cvreleaseCapture(). I thought there might be any other solution. Please let me know.

Comment: There's another similar question here actually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691546/cant-find-releasecapture-in-opencv-while-using-python

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.destroyAllWindows()` should be called upon some condition (such as a key press)