# how to correctly use webcam in opencv using python wrappers?

Tags: python, opencv

Currently, I have this working example:

```
import cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

cv.NamedWindow('image')

while True:

    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage('image', frame)

    k = cv.WaitKey(10)

    if k % 256 == 27:
        break

cv.DestroyWindow('image');
```

But, the resource is not properly release. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6974470/1094999) suggests using `del(capture)` but, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770328/1094999) other recommends using `cvReleaseCapute` (but I can't find that function ).

Which is the correct way to release the capture?

This is my opencv version:

```
In [4]: from cv2 import __version__
In [5]: __version__
Out[5]: '$Rev: 4557 $'
```

Comment: `cvReleaseCapute` -> `cv.ReleaseCapture`?

Comment: `In [12]: cv.ReleaseCapture()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ReleaseCapture'`

Comment: Can't you just say `capture = None`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `cv2.VideoCapture` and `capture.release()` (`cv2` instead of `cv`)

```
import cv2, cv

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   

flag, im_array = capture.read()

image = cv.fromarray(im_array)

cv.SaveImage('output.jpeg', image)

capture.release()                   # release it
```